# How can I hide my div when I click on it and inside it, and not hide when I click on certain components inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to hide my div when the user clicks/taps on it, however, if the user clicks/taps on a button/input field/image etc inside the div, I do not want to hide it. How can I achieve this using jquery?

Below is the code

***Mark up in Jade (Pug)***

```
.occasion#occasion-header
      .heading
        span.number 1
        span#title Occasion
        span#chosen &nbsp- Birthay
        span#change Change
      #inside-text-occasion
        p#inside-title-occasion Select an occasion.
        #occasion-cards
          each card in spec.occasioncards
            +egreeting-card(card)
      br
      hr
      

    .recipient#recipient-header 
      .heading
        span.number 2
        span#title Name of Recipient
      #inside-text-recipient
        input#name(type="text")
```

***jquery code***

```
   
    $("#occasion-header").on('click', function(){
      $("#inside-text-occasion").toggle();
    });

    $("#recipient-header").on('click', function(){
      $("#inside-text-recipient").toggle();
    });
```

***This is how the UI looks like***

I want to be able to hide the `Occasion` div if I click anywhere inside the div, except for the occasion cards e.g. Birthday, Congratulations etc.

Similarly for the second screenshot, I want to be able to hide the `Name of Recipient` div when the user clicks inside the div anywhere except the input field where he/she enters the name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use **stopPropagation()** on the clickable elements within to prevent the click event from bubbling up.

Comment: You need to specify the event and stop propagation on that event `$(".egreeting-card").on('click', function( event ) { event.stopPropagation(); });`